# Geting the first image url from a post?

Tags: php

I am trying to create a dynamic website, I have a database with some news, and I wanted to get the first image from the post content

How can I get the first image of the post and display the link?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? You have an url of an external page of which you'd like to get the first image, or do you have your own database with images?

Comment: hello, i have my own database with images, but i need to fileter them and get the url,how can this be done. thnx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/).

Comment: Its not from an external site, its from his own database