# Getting the first image url from a post?

Tags: php, image, filter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Geting the first image url from a post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027770/geting-the-first-image-url-from-a-post)

I am trying to create a dynamic website, I have a database with some news, and I wanted to get the first image from the post content, the images are at my database, not an external one.

How can I get the first image of the post and display the link?

Comment: Could we maybe have a bit of code to see what you've tried?

Comment: Please provide us with some more information, what db are you using, what format is the post in (xml, html, rss, etc.).

Comment: Can you explain better what you want? Do you want to parse the news message for some UBB code or something?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7027770/22470

Comment: please do not repost questions.

Comment: @AvinD: You have already marked an answer as the correct one in the previous post with the exact same question. If you're having further problems please edit the previous one with more details or post a new question if it's about some specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the news is stored (HTML?). But an easy way is to just go through the markup character by character until you hit the first image (in HTML, this would be denoted by a `<img />` tag.

You can use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to find the first occurrence of a substring in a string. And then you can use [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to extract the image.

Comment: hello, can u give an example please ? thank you

Comment: please can you give an example  ?